# Acceder a una variable privada de un objeto pasado como parámetro

Tags: java, variables, parametros, alcance

Tengo la clase Fraccion

```
package clases;

public class Fraccion {
    
    private int num, den;
    
    public Fraccion() {
        this.num = 0;
        this.den = 0;
    }
    
    public void prueba(Fraccion x) {
        x.num = 1;
        x.den = 1;
    }
    
    public void mostrar() {
        System.out.println(" num: " + num + " . den: "+ den);
    }
    
    public void modificar(int x, int y){
        num = x;
        den = y;
    }
}
```

En el método prueba, recibo como parámetro un objeto de la clase `Fraccion` y puedo acceder al estado del parámetro, aun cuando lo declare como privado.
Hice lo mismo desde una clase distinta y hay si me respetó el modificador de alcance.
¿Cuál sería la causa de este comportamiento?.

Comment: cual fue tu prueba unitaria algo como: Fraccion f = new Fraccion();
        f.mostrar();
        f.prueba(f);
        f.mostrar();
        f.modificar(50, 2);
        f.mostrar();
        
        Fraccion f1 = new Fraccion();
        f1.prueba(f);
        f.mostrar(); ?

Comment: @RuslanLópez no entiendo por qué preguntas cuál fue su prueba unitaria. En ningún momento menciona una prueba unitaria en la pregunta.

Comment: Este post responde tu pregunta? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027139/access-private-field-of-another-object-in-same-class

Comment: @AndresGardiol sé que no lo emnciona, pero como su clase no tiene main no presentaría ningún problema. Prueba unitaria se refiere a la forma en que lo corre, a su escenario de ejecución no a algúna prueba unitaria por código.

Comment: @RuslanLópez en la pregunta, el OP no menciona ningún problema con su código. Su pregunta está relacionada con un comportamiento de alcance de variables privadas. Por lo que no veo necesario que muestre cómo corre su código :)

Answer (score 2):

Como estás accediendo a un miembro privado dentro del cuerpo del mismo tipo que lo declara, esto está permitido.

Debemos tener claro que la visibilidad de los miembros de una clase en Java se maneja a nivel de tipo de dato y no de instancias. Por esto no importa que le pases un objeto cualquiera al método `prueba()`, como el tipo de este objeto es la propia clase, pues tiene acceso a todos sus miembros privados.

De la especificación del lenguaje:

> A member (class, interface, field, or method) of a reference type, or a constructor of a class type, is accessible only if the type is accessible and the member or constructor is declared to permit access:
>
> - Otherwise, the member or constructor is declared private, and access is permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level type (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor.